# JQuery Datatables overflow

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have settled my datables within a tabbed container, If the table is too long, it overflows. The following code resizes the columns when i change tabs:

```
$('#tmTabs').tabs( {
    "show": function(event, ui) {

        var oTable = $('div.dataTables_scrollBody>table.display', ui.panel).dataTable();
        if ( oTable.length > 0 ) {
            oTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
        }
    }
} );
```

but, is a bit taxing on processing time and this current code only works when you change the tab.  The table overflows, when any operation is called on it, that being sorting, adding a row, or filtering etc.

Heres a screenshot of the overflow, you can see on the right side, as pointed by the arrow (just blanked out the data with white boxes, so dont worry about those):

[image: data tables overflows right-side]

If necessary, heres the rest of my code to create the dataTables (i am also using the editable plugin):

```
$('.dataTable').each(function(){ 
    //get ID of current table;
    tblID = $(this).attr("id");
    var pattern = "[0-9]+";
    $tblIDNum = tblID.match(pattern);

    //transform this table into a data table
    $(this).dataTable({ 
        "sScrollY": "600px",
        "bScrollCollapse": true,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            { "sWidth": "10%", "aTargets": [ -1 ] }
            ]
        }) 

    .makeEditable({
            //ajax requests for server-side processing
            sUpdateURL: "UpdateData.php",
            sAddURL: "AddData.php",
            sDeleteURL: "DeleteData.php",

            //Button Customization
            oAddNewRowButtonOptions: { 
            label: "Add...",
                            icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-plus' }
                        },
                        oDeleteRowButtonOptions: {
            label: "Remove",
                            icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-trash' }
                        },
                        oAddNewRowOkButtonOptions: {
            label: "Confirm",
                            icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-check' },
                            name: "action",
                            value: "add-new"
                        },
                        oAddNewRowCancelButtonOptions: { 
            label: "Close",
                            class: "back-class",
                            name: "action",
                            value: "cancel-add",
                            icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-close' }
                        },
            oAddNewRowFormOptions: {
                title: 'Add New Row',
                show: "blind",
                hide: "explode"
                },

            //Link button ids
            sAddDeleteToolbarSelector: ".dataTables_length",
            sAddNewRowFormId: "formAddNewRow"+$tblIDNum,
            sAddNewRowButtonId: "btnAddNewRow"+$tblIDNum,
            sAddNewRowOkButtonId: "btnAddNewRowOk"+$tblIDNum,
            sAddNewRowCancelButtonId: "btnAddNewRowCancel"+$tblIDNum,
            sDeleteRowButtonId: "btnDeleteRow"+$tblIDNum                                
            });

});
```

What could the solution be? I don't think should be difficult, if it weren't for all the Javascript, a CSS overflow property could just be changed. Makes me regret using Datatables. : /

Answer (score 3):

add `"sScrollX": "100%"`

```
   $(this).dataTable({ 
        "sScrollX": "100%",
        "sScrollY": "600px",
        "bScrollCollapse": true,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            { "sWidth": "10%", "aTargets": [ -1 ] }
            ]
        })
```

Comment: This works, but it seems to stop the columns from resizing, is there a way to keep both? (I just want it to resize the columns to fill the width of the table).

And another issue it works fine on firefox v7.0, but one google chrome on some of my tables, a blank block appears on the table.