# JQuery Datatables columns overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I have problem with my datatable: it has to have a specific width, but also I want to display all its columns. The whole issue looks like this:

[image: overflow]

I found solutions [Datatables Width Overflow For A Lot Of Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655001/datatables-width-overflow-for-a-lot-of-columns) and [JQuery Datatables overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655508/jquery-datatables-overflow), but I would rather use word breaking then have a scrollbar in my table.

So, I found another solution [jQuery DataTable overflow and text-wrapping issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058109/jquery-datatable-overflow-and-text-wrapping-issues) according to which i had to set:

```
  table.display { table-layout:fixed; }
  th, td { word-wrap:break-word; overflow:hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; }
```

However, with this I had a problem with column width; all columns have same width and option "bAutoWidth: true" is ignored:
[image]

For example, there is an empty horizontal space in *Price* column, or after icons at last column. Moreover word-broken headers (th) seem very ugly, and it would look better if *Code*, *Count*, *Price* and *Place* columns were at their minimum size (their width matched width of header text).

I would like to specify (somehow) preferred width for each column, or after how many letters it should wrap. I found [breakCellText plugin](https://bitbucket.org/JustinP8/datatables.breakcelltext) in this post [jQuery DataTable overflow and text-wrapping issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058109/jquery-datatable-overflow-and-text-wrapping-issues). Nevertheless, this plugin is not working with my datatables 1.9.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. Here is my solution:

```
.dt-index {
    column-width: auto !important;
}
```

Please use this style for your table.

I hope that will be your solution.

Greetz
Vegeta_77